# List views in OS X Notification Center

Tags: xcode, macos, widget, swift

I'm planning to program a little widget for the OS X 10.10 Yosemite Notification Center that includes a list displaying data in a custom format. But that's my problem: How do you implement a natural-looking list view into the OS X Notification Center? In iOS I just would have added a UITableView that also adapts to the vibrant design of the Notification Center. But unfortunately in OS X there is no such component providing the same features because the Table View provided by looks really weird inside the Notification Center mainly because it doesn't adapt to the design. So is there a component providing the required features (similar to an UITableView on iOS) or does anyone know how this problem was solved in the system's widgets?

I really appreciate all your help!

Answer (score 1):

Can't you use NSTableView as the cocoa version of UITableView?

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSTableView_Class/index.html

Comment: Unfortunately not, because it just looks ugly (the vibrancy effect doesn't work) and doesn't provide the features needed.

Comment: I've just started to a similar case and I will update my answer after trying a list in Today bar for cocoa.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I'm also going to try it for myself a little bit more - maybe this feature got added in a later XCode version.